# Junit 5 - How to pass in multiple null values for @CsvSource?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I am modifying a test method from single parameter to multiple:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@NullSource
@ValueSource({"foo", "bar"..})
void shouldReturnFalse(String x) {
  assertThat(someMethod(x)).isFalse();
}

@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({
  "null, null",
  "foo, bar"
})
void shouldReturnFalse(String x, String y) {
  assertThat(someMethod(x, y)).isFalse();
}
```

`null` here is passed in as a String literal instead of a null literal. As a result, this test fails. This test previously works with single argument with `@NullSource`, but it gives following error when switched to multiple:

> org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter...

I couldn't find a workaround for this and the solutions I saw were rather hacky and cumbersome. Is there a easier way for providing values with `null`?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`@CsvSource` has an attribute called `nullValues`.
See the [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.params/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/CsvSource.html#nullValues()).

> A list of strings that should be interpreted as null references.

```
@CsvSource(value= {"null, null",
                   "foo, bar"}
           , nullValues={"null"})
```

---

The other option is to simply don't pass any value as stated in the previously linked documentation.

> Please note that unquoted empty values will always be converted to null references regardless of the value of this nullValues attribute; whereas, a quoted empty string will be treated as an emptyValue().

```
@CsvSource({",",
            "foo, bar"})
```

Comment: To be clear, you can achieve both `null` and empty string `""` values in the same test by using single quotes (`'`) like in this example: `@CsvSource(value = { "null, null", "'', ''" }, nullValues = { "null" })`

Answer (score 12):

You can use nullValues as explained above by @Jan Schmitz, or you can just discard null values like this:

```java
@CsvSource({
  ",",
  "foo, bar"
})
```