# Junit 5 - How to pass multiple null values for @MethodSource?

Tags: java, junit5

Very similar to [how to pass multiple null value for CSVSource][Junit 5 - How to pass in multiple null values for @CsvSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207427/junit-5-how-to-pass-in-multiple-null-values-for-csvsource)

I am modifying a test method from single parameter to multiple:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@NullAndEmptySource
@MethodSource("generateData")
void testSomeMethod(String x,List<String> list) {
  doSomethingwith(x);
  doAnotherThingWith(list);
}

private static Stream<Arguments> generateData() {
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of("a", Arrays.asList("1","2","3")),
        Arguments.of("b", Arrays.asList("1","2","3")),
        Arguments.of("foo", Arrays.asList("1","2","3"))
    );
}
```

null and empty testcase added by this annotation `@NullAndEmptySource` failed with a ParameterResolutionException:No parameter registered for parameter [java.util.List<java.lang.String> arg1 in method [public void my.pachage.myclass.testSomeMethod]

Could anyone please guide me to pass the test case? I have no idea whether parameters matches because there are two parameters in the method and I don't understand what does the error message mean.

Answer (score 0):

This error is encountered because `@NullAndEmptySource` is used on a method with more than one parameter (I tested it locally).
To pass the test, you should probably add the null and empty test cases in the stream returned by `generateData()`.